# Некорректно работает тег activity в Manifest

Tags: android

Есть одно `MainActivity`, у него `label="ПРОГА"`.
Название приложение "Андроид". Надо сделать так, чтобы в `Launchere` отображался текст данной проги "Андроид", а при запуске текст в `MainActivity` в ActionBar был "Прога".

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="LikeMobile"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:label="СОВЕТЫ"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_advice">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Data"/>
        <activity android:name=".Settings"/>
    </application>
```

[image: изображение]

Comment: <application> по сути и есть Ваше приложение. Вы как бы говорите в Манифесте: "Я хочу чтоб мое приложение имело иконку  @mipmap/ic_launcher и Называлось @string/app_name." 
Что здесь работает некорректно? Уточниет вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, Вот именно что по логике так и получается, но на деле, если в `<activity MainActivity` добавить `label` и `icon`, то все что в `<application` будет игнорироваться. И текст и иконка которые указанные в `<activity MainActivity`  будут отображаться и в Launchere, и в самом приложении

Comment: @xTIGRx Теоретически, `application` не может быть показано. Все, что Вы видите на экране - это `activity`. И у каждой `activity` есть своя иконка и название. Если не установить эти параметры для `<activity>`, будут использоваться параметры из тега `<application>`.

Comment: Блин вы хоть понимаете о чем речь идет?)), такое ощущение что вы специально пишете это все). Я же говорю в LAUNCHERE. Тобишь в  андроид в том месте где все проги видны. ТАМ моя прога отображается с другим названием. КОТОРАЯ указанная в <activity и это не правильно)

Comment: @DanielShatz, Вот именно что нет :). там написано `android:label="LikeMobile"`

Comment: @xTIGRx в лаунчере показываются *активити*, а не приложения. Приложение запустить нельзя. Запустить можно активити. Поэтому в лаунчере показывается название из тега `activity`. Это стандартное поведение Android.

Comment: Я понял проблему, попробую сейчас подробней ответить. Здесь пока не вижу корректного ответа.

Comment: @xTIGRx, правки вносятся для улучшения качества вопросов и ответов. Для вас лично это может не иметь значения, но улучшит опыт будущих читателей. Если есть вопросы по работе сайта, не стесняйтесь спрашивать на Мете и в чате http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @Nofate, "Для вас лично это может не иметь значения", вы тут глубоко ошибаетесь, У вас система такая если нет очков репутации или много плохх отзывов то данному человеку дается бан. Если мне тут просто будут давать отрицательные оценки на уже отвеченные вопросы, то я скоро Бан могу получить, Система у вас такая. Так что лично для меня это как раз таки имеет БОЛЬШОЕ значение.

Comment: @xTIGRx, бан не дается автоматически за минусы. Бан дается за некачественные вопросы/ответы, агрессию и вандализм.

Comment: Странно, а на английском stack меня заблокировали за то что много вопросов задавал...А как можно узнать вопрос качественный или нет, Не может быть вопроса качественного, ведь вопросы не по шаблону задаются, каждый человек выражает свои мысли как может, кто - то более грамотно, кто - то нет, и что если тот кто не может грамотно свою мысль в вопросе выразить его нужно банить? Странно  все это, слишком жестоко, так дело и до рассизма дойти может, если ты черный и задал вопрос бан тебе... Я допустим не могу гармотно мысль выражать, если бы мог, то гуглом пользовался...

Comment: @xTIGRx, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В лаунчере отображаются все `activity`, и соответственно их параметры берутся из тега `activity` в манифесте. Поменяйте label и icon для тега `activity` - эти параметры будут переданы **в саму `Activity`**.

Если добавить `label` в `intent filter`, этот label будет отображен **в лаунчере**.
В вашем случае вот так:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="LikeMobile"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="СОВЕТЫ"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_advice">
        <intent-filter android:label="LikeMobile">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Data"/>
    <activity android:name=".Settings"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Тогда в самом MainActivity уже будет текст LikeMobile, что не правильно, должно быть в ActionBar в MainActivity текст "Советы"

Comment: @xTIGRx посмотрите теперь

Comment: Да то что нужно)

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за пояснения вопроса.

В вашем случае получается такая ситуация:

в элементе application вы указали:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

После чего icon и label используются по умолчанию, во всех! компонентах приложения.

Но изменения в MainActivity.class значений icon или label будут изменять икону или лейбл в Launcher. Так как:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Вы настроили Activity как Launcher. Те меняя icon либо label вы распостроняетение это значение на Intent. По сути вы выбрали это активити, как средство в запуске (Launcher) и вывод прост, что заданные в фильтре label и icon будут отображаются в средстве запуска.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Есть [application label](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), есть [activity label](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Если не задан `label` для `Activity`, то используется тот, что в `application` части прописан. Приоритет `icon` и `label` атрибутов у `activity` больше, чем в `application`.

P.S. в ActionBar текст любой можно задать:

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

Comment: Может есть способ приоритет поменять?

Есть одно MainActivity, у него label "ПРОГА". Само название приложение "Андроид".
Надо сделать так чтобы в Launchere отображался текст данной проги "Андроид", а при запуске Текст в MainActivity в ActionBar был "Прога"

Comment: Приоритет задан спецификацией. Не думаю, что возможно что-то с этим поделать. А в ActionBar текст можно любой задать. setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);